# Phone app crashes during phone calls

Tags: troubleshooting

On my Android phone the Phone app will crash when taking or placing calls is there some way to replace the phone.apk?

Comment: What phone do you have?

Comment: Xperia P stock Android 4.1.2 rooted ( I had the problem before i rooted it)